# The ambiguity of negative imperative

Tags: commas, imperatives

**11) Don't just sit there and introduce yourself!**

**12) Don't just sit around and eat!**

Is it right that those two sentences eventually convey Don't sit and also don't introduce in #11 and "don't sit and also don't eat" in #12?

If there were commas in front of "and" as follows, then could they change the meanings and the sentences eventually say that you have to introduce, not sitting there in #21, and you have to eat, not sitting around in #22?

**21) **Don't just sit there, and introduce yourself!**

**22) Don't just sit around, and eat!**

Then if the two commas should be left out, you can't still understand them just as there were commas?

Comment: Example (11) doesn't sound idiomatic to me. I'd prefer (21a) _Don't just sit there – introduce yourself!_ or (21b) _Don't just sit there. [And] introduce yourself!_ (The alternative reading is most unlikely. If it is considered to make sense, (11b)  _Don't just sit there introducing yourself!_ is unambiguous.) // Example (12) is more idiomatic, and would be taken as meaning (12a) _Don't just sit around eating!_ //  Again, I'd want a heavier-duty stop than a comma to show the fact that there are two instructions rather than a coordinated one: (22a) Don't just sit around. [And] eat [something]!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In natural speech, the syntactic pause and corroborating intonation patterns of such imperatives resolve any ambiguity (if context does not). In text, punctuation (a comma, or a dash if the "and" is dropped, which it can be) would attempt to reflect those contours of speech.

> Don't just sit there, and introduce yourself!
>
> Don't just sit there—introduce yourself!

**Introduce yourself! Don't just sit there.**

> Don't just sit around and eat!

**Don't be a lazy bumpkin who does nothing but stuff his pie-hole.**

> Don't just sit around, and eat!

**Get up! Enjoy yourself. Look at all the delicious food. Have some!**